# Wordpress/Elementor Hamburger Menu issue

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a website for a friend using wordpress and elementor. I'm struggling to understand why the drop-down menu won't work when I put to a mobile screen resolution. When I'm editing it within the elementor editor, it works fine, when I publish it it doesn't work at all.

http://jungledlondon.com/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found an error triggered by JavaScript.
I found this on Chrome Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main-menu.js?ver=1.0.3:24)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

I'm not sullying sure about this, but it looks that the js code that makes the primary button displays the main menu is not working.
If you are the developer you need to check that code again.

Below is the entire function that is triggering this error:

```
( function( $ ) {
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Nav Main DD Toggle
    $( ".navbarprimary .dropdowntoggle" ).click(function() {
        if( $(this).parent('li').hasClass('navbarprimary-open') ) {
            $(this).parent('li').removeClass('navbarprimary-open');
        } else {
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('navbarprimary-open');
        }

        if( $(this).children('span').hasClass('fa-chevron-circle-down') ) {
            $(this).children('span').removeClass('fa-chevron-circle-down');
            $(this).children('span').addClass('fa-chevron-circle-right');
        } else {
            $(this).children('span').removeClass('fa-chevron-circle-right');
            $(this).children('span').addClass('fa-chevron-circle-down');
        }

        return false;
    });

    // Sticky nav bar
    var h = $('.navbarprimary').offset().top;
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if( $(this).scrollTop() > h ) {
            $('.navbarprimary').addClass('sticky_menu_top');
        } else {
            $('.navbarprimary').removeClass('sticky_menu_top');
        }

    });

});
} )( jQuery );
```